# JavaScript function not returning an output. Not sure if my variables are in the right place

Tags: javascript, variables, scope

Not sure why this doesn't have an output. This should return 6 but it's not returning anything. What am I doing wrong?

```js
var stock_prices = [10, 7, 5, 8, 11, 9]

function getMaxProfit(stock_prices){
  var current_price = stock_prices[0]
  var min_price = current_price
  var max_profit = 0
  var current_profit = 0
  for (var i = 0; i < stock_prices.length; i++){
    if (current_price < min_price){
      min_price = current_price
      current_profit = current_price - min_price
      if (current_profit > max_profit){
        max_profit = current_profit
      }
    }
  }
  return max_profit
}

console.log(getMaxProfit(stock_prices))
```

Comment: are you sure your `current_price` variable is in the right place?

Comment: You never change the current_price variable. Assign its value on the first line of your for, such as current_price == stock_prices[i]

Comment: It's not returning nothing, it's returning 0 - there is a big difference.

Comment: you may want to use `;` here and there

Comment: current_price is ten which is not less than 0, so it returns max profit which is 0.

Comment: At least a couple of problems: 1. You're just forgetting to update `current_price` in the loop. 2. You do `min_price = current_price` and then on the next line use the result of `current_price - min_price` -- which will always be 0, you **just** made them the same. It's not clear to me at all how it's *supposed* to work, but those are two issues that jump out.

Comment: Instead of asking *us* to debug your code for you, use the powerful debugger built into your browser to do it. You can step through the code statement by statement, look at the state of variables as you go along, etc.

Comment: The problem is these two lines: `min_price = current_price;
      current_profit = current_price - min_price`. You set min_price equal to current_price, and then subtract the two, meaning you will always get zero.

Comment: Are you just trying to find difference between highest and lowest stock price? - like 11 - 5 = 6

Comment: Got it. Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, based on what you provide, I think you want to get the difference between the highest and lowest number on your array (what you're calling "profit") because you want it to return 6.

The following code does that and return the previously-said value :

```
function getMaxProfit(stock_prices){
  var current_price = stock_prices[0];
  var min_price = current_price
  var max_profit = 0
  var current_profit = 0
  for (var i = 0; i < stock_prices.length; i++){
    current_price = stock_prices[i];
    if (current_price > min_price){
      current_profit = current_price - min_price
      if (current_profit > max_profit){
        max_profit = current_profit
      }
    }
    else
      {
        min_price = current_price;
      }
  }
  return max_profit
}
```

Comment: That's **one** problem. But fixing it won't stop the function from always returning `0`.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you!!

Comment: Your edited answer does nothing more than point out what has already been said in the comments. Can you propose a solution?

Comment: @mhodges I didn't see the comment, deleting the answer,as it provides nothing

Comment: @Sorikairo Well, just edit the answer with a proposed solution, we'd be happy to upvote if it's useful

Comment: @mhodges Nevermind, I think I found what author wanted to do.

Comment: @mhodges Edited with an answer sir.

Answer (score 0):

On looping process you are missing to increment value of current_price. This will always print your ans 0. As it check 10 > 10, its false so it gives you 0 output and iteration carries on going but current_price remains stock_prices[0] = 10. So after i < 6, it comes out of loop and prints 0 as your ans. So after loop set current_price = stock_price[i]. This allows to change value of current_price. If any confusion then please comment.